# I got a Assembler error while compile mt19937

Tags: c++, random, compiler-errors, gnu

I have a C++ file `test.cc` as below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main()
{
    std::mt19937 rng(347 * 6007);
    std::cout << rng() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

when I use command `g++ ./test.cc -o test -O3 -march=native` compile it, it failed:

```
[csc@fedora examples]$ g++ ./test.cc -o test -O3 -march=native
/tmp/ccvnwhuu.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccvnwhuu.s:38: Error: selected processor does not support `eor3 v0.16b,v1.16b,v3.16b,v0.16b'
/tmp/ccvnwhuu.s:73: Error: selected processor does not support `eor3 v0.16b,v1.16b,v6.16b,v0.16b'
```

but if I use command `g++ ./test.cc -o test -O3` or `g++ ./test.cc -o test -march=native`, it worked

Why this happened?

I'm using `Linux fedora 6.5.10-200.fc38.aarch64` virtual machine with apple M1 chip(`arm`), and my g++ version is `g++ (GCC) 13.2.1 20231011 (Red Hat 13.2.1-4)`

Comment: And GCC version is...

Comment: What's the VM running in?

Comment: Side note: nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that `std::endl` does. Use `'\n'` to end a line unless there's a good reason not to.

Comment: One of your working commands is is identical to the non-working command.

Comment: @tadman Vmware Fusion Player 13.5.1

Comment: @273K Sorry I forgot that, g++ version is `g++ (GCC) 13.2.1 20231011 (Red Hat 13.2.1-4)`